# Backbone loses dropdown events when moving between views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a view that defines several events like this:

```
events: {
    'click .js-icon-remove': 'removeFilter',
    'change .select-control': 'updateFilters',
    'click #btn_search': 'requestSearch',
    'click #btn_add_search': 'requestSaveSearch'
}
```

The three click events are on buttons or links while the change event is on a dropdown.  When the view first renders, all events work fine.  However, when I go to a different page and then come back to this view, the dropdown event is lost.  If I reload the browser, things work fine again.  They even work fine multiple times, not just the first time.  It's just when I re-render the view that the event binding is lost.

I have tried changing the event from a change to a click, or from the class to the element (select rather than .select-control).  All things will work the first time the view is rendered and that's it.

Comment: After a little more research, I came upon using `this.delegateEvents()` to re-bind the events.  This is working fine now but I'm still not comfortable with this solution.  I don't see why I should have to do this manually.  Also, I'm still interested to know why it is only some events which are lost.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I go to a different page" and "when I re-render"?

Comment: If I fire another route which renders a different view, then go back either by clicking a link or by using the back button.

Comment: Do you get the same exact behavior in both situations, clicking a link or hitting the back-button? And I should add, are you firing a route when clicking a link? (kind of an anti-pattern when using Backbone routes)

Comment: There's not enough information to know what's going on with your events, sorry.

Comment: @kinakuta: Yes, the same behavior happens when clicking a link as clicking the back button.  I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the next question.  Some links are just href's, which I suppose will fire a route.

Comment: @muistooshort: I'll try to create a simplified test case later if possible but right now there's too much code for me to post.

Comment: What I meant was are you triggering routes with a navigate call.

Comment: @kinakuta: No, they're just plain <a> links, but those do trigger routes.  What are you getting at?

Comment: @kinakuta: Also, can you give me more info on this anti-pattern you're referring to?  Do you know of any page that explains what you're talking about further?

Comment: When you call the navigate method on your router, you can pass an additional option that triggers your route {trigger: true}. This would be the alternative to letting natural actions trigger your routes and just using navigate to update the url in reaction to changes. So the difference is whether your router is just handling routes or also manually triggering them itself.

Comment: Well first of all, I'm not using navigate(), these are just plain old <a> links.

Second of all, if I were to use navigate(), it wouldn't be from within the router.  It would from some view code or such.  So the router would still just be handling routes.  I don't see any situation where anyone would be triggering routes from within a router.

Third of all, if you suspect that something is going on here as a result of that, then let me know and maybe I can just directly test for that because all this beating around the route bush is getting us nowhere.

Comment: I'm not sure what beating around the bush you're referring to, but if you're that put of by my asking simple questions that only required simple answers, then I'll withdraw my help. Good luck.

Comment: @kinakuta: I don't understand why you're getting offended. I do appreciate your help.  My point is, you're asking all these questions in order to determine if something is happening and yet you haven't mentioned once what it is you're actually trying to determine.  That's what I mean by beating around the bush. What is it that you're trying to figure out?

Answer (score 0):

This is getting into how event binding works in Backbone and the DOM.

When a view renders, and it's $el is added to the DOM, backbone binds the events automatically. However, once you remove the view's $el from the dom, those events will then need to be re-bound when the $el is added back into the dom. This is what your delegateEvents() method is doing.

A best practice when working in backbone is to make views disposable, eg don't keep them around after they are removed from the DOM. When you navigate away from the view, and remove it from the dom, then navigate back, you should re-instantiate the view, render it, and add it to the dom again. You can keep you models and collections around, so you don't have  refetch data, but views work better when they are either left in the dom or are recreated each time they are added/ removed.

I highly recommend Marionette.js, and specifically it's region class. It saves you a lot of boilerplate code when it comes to view handling.